# How to transform/flip this data set around on its side?

Tags: sql-server-2012

My data looks like this:

```
PhoneNumber | Department
9495551234  | Sales
9495554598  | Sales
9494582045  | Sales
9495639842  | Sales
9496573952  | Accounting
9498730956  | Marketing
9498346620  | Marketing
```

I want the data to look like this:

```
Sales       | Accounting     | Marketing
9495551234  | 9496573952     | 9498730956  
9495554598  |   <blank>      | 9498346620  
9494582045  |   <blank>      |   <blank>
9495639842  |   <blank>      |   <blank>
```

Is this done with a PIVOT perhaps? Am I leaving out any info here or is this straight forward enough?

Comment: Yes, Pivot can do that

Comment: I cannot find any examples of Pivot that do something simple and similar to this. :-/

Comment: I am not sure how to make it account for the blanks. In fact, I cannot get an example working at all and I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT`

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/92438/15/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE tab(PhoneNumber NVARCHAR(20), Department NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO tab(PhoneNumber, Department)
VALUES
('9495551234'  , 'Sales'),
('9495554598'  , 'Sales'),
('9494582045'  , 'Sales'),
('9495639842'  , 'Sales'),
('9496573952'  , 'Accounting'),
('9498730956'  , 'Marketing'),
('9498346620'  , 'Marketing');
```

Query:

```
;WITH cte AS
(  SELECT 
      PhoneNumber,
      Department,
      [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
  FROM tab
)
SELECT 
     [Sales]      = IIF(Sales IS NOT NULL, Sales, '<blank>')
    ,[Accounting] = IIF(Accounting IS NOT NULL, Accounting, '<blank>')
    ,[Marketing]  = IIF(Marketing IS NOT NULL, Marketing, '<blank>')
FROM cte
PIVOT
(
  MAX(PhoneNumber)
  FOR Department IN (Sales, Accounting, Marketing)
) AS p;
```

Comment: You NAILED it! The IIF() part as well as the Row_Number parts are both new to me. I am also still confused as to how the MAX() part works with this. It seems to me that it would be used as a summary of data rather than how it actually comes out. But, regardless, this is very cool and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `IIF` can be changed to `ISNULL(Sales, '<blank>')`, `MAX()` is just for getting one value because `PIVOT` wants aggregate function, `ROW_NUMBER` is simple rank function. Happy I can help :)